# Is there a nicer/smarter way to filter in JavaScript than adding lots of cumbersome extras?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of about 30 objects. Some of the objects behave differently so in my test I need to filter them out.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
myArray.filter(item => item.name !== 'something' && item.name !== 'somethingElse' && item.name !== 'a third thing')
```

This is tiring, ugly and error prone. Is there anyway I can make this a bit nicer?

Secondly, for my second test I would like to test these items. Is there any way I can negate this filter so that it includes just these items? Currently I have to do the hugely laborious:

```
myArray.filter(item => item.name === 'something' && item.name === 'somethingElse' && item.name === 'a third thing')
```

which isn't good. Any ideas?

Comment: the last one can not have different values at the same time.

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry it should be `||`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save all the item names you want to filter in an array and then filter based on that array?

```
const filteredItemNames = ['something', 'somethingElse', 'a third thing'];
const filteredItems = myArray.filter(item => !filteredItemNames.includes(item.name));
```

Which you could then also easily reverse by doing

```
const filteredItems = myArray.filter(item => filteredItemNames.includes(item.name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method:

```
const desiredObjectNames = ['something', 'somethingElse', 'a third thing'];
myArray.filter(obj => desiredObjectNames.includes(obj);
```

or vice versa

```
myArray.filter(obj => !desiredObjectNames.includes(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

From this

```
myArray.filter(item =>
    item.name !== 'something' &&
    item.name !== 'somethingElse' &&
    item.name !== 'a third thing'
);
```

the inversion is by using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
myArray.filter(item =>
    item.name === 'something' ||
    item.name === 'somethingElse' ||
    item.name === 'a third thing'
);
```

The last one could be written with a `Set`,

```
var items = new Set(['something', 'somethingElse', 'a third thing'],
    filtered = myArray.filter(({ name }) => items.has(name));
```

as well as the first one with

```
var items = new Set(['something', 'somethingElse', 'a third thing'],
    filtered = myArray.filter(({ name }) => !items.has(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array in which you put all the names that should be rejected/accepted

```
var reject = [
'something',
'somethingElse',
'a third thing'
]

var accept= [
'something',
'somethingElse',
'a third thing'
]

// reject if in array
myArray.filter(item => reject.indexOf(item) === -1)

// just accept if in array
myArray.filter(item => accept.indexOf(item) >= 0)
```